# How to convert UTC datetime to another timezone?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

How can i convert a date like this: `2012-07-16 01:00:00 +00` (it's in the `UTC +00:00` timezone) to `UTC +04:00` timezone? Ensuring that daylight saving will be handelled correctly?

Comment: @Matt not really, he is asking how to convert a string based timezone offset into a real offset.

Comment: If this were a duplicate, that comment would hardly have been useless.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`DateTimeZone`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php).

```
$date = new DateTime('2012-07-16 01:00:00 +00');
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Moscow')); // +04

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2012-07-15 05:00:00
```

Comment: @Florent If I only have the offset "+04", how can I modify this approach??

Answer (score 1):

The `DateTimeZone` constructor can explicitly accept a UTC offset, which I understand you have.

```
//So For 'Asia/Kolkata' you need to use 

$timeZone = new DateTimeZone('+0530');

// Example 

$utc = new DateTime("1960-08-08T20:40:00Z");
echo $utc->format('Y-m-d H:i:s T')."<br>";
$tz =new DateTimeZone('+0530');
$utc->setTimezone($tz);
echo $utc->format('Y-m-d H:i:s T');
```

Output:
1960-08-08 20:40:00 Z
1960-08-09 02:10:00 GMT+0530

I guess this is easiest and simplest way to convert time to any given Offset

Documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.construct.php

*Note: per that documentation link, this new constructor usage has been available since PHP version 5.5.10.*

Answer (score 0):

To help with the solution, you need to get the last part of the string (the offset part) and look it up against a simple lookup. you can use a regex or `substr()` (maybe) to get the offest part. Then, when you have a + or - value, use a maximum of 24 lookups against possible timezones which you can use with PHP's possible [timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) - if the offset is the same, who cares what the actual country/location is?

The use [date_default_timezone_set](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to apply the right one.

Answer (score -3):

You can also use GMT time also and convert it to your requirement afterwards

```
<?php
echo gmdate("M d Y H:i:s", mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1998));
?>
```

GMT refers Greenwich Mean Time which is common all over the world.