# Get time at midnight(00:00:00) from a date

Tags: php, date, datetime

I am trying to convert a date to a timestamp at the exact midnight point.
To do this, I am using the following little function.

```
function converttotimestamp($date)
{

    $date = str_replace('/', '-', $date);
    $date = $date.' 00:00:00';
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y H:i:s',$date);
    return $date->getTimestamp();
}
```

So as you can see, I am attaching a midnight time at the end.
I tried using this as shown below

```
echo converttotimestamp('7/22/2014');
```

So as you would expect when you run this in a unix converter, you would get `1405987200`.

But In my case it returns `1405976400` whicj translates to `Mon, 21 Jul 2014 21:00:00`.

Oh. I am in Kenya.

Comment: uHM, Because I am Kenyan??????

Answer (score 1):

The reason you may be seeing a different time returned than the one you were expecting is likely because you haven't considered the relevant timezones. There are a couple different ways you can set the timezone. You can set it during runtime:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

You can set it in your PHP config file:

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone

Or you can set the timezone of your DateTime object:

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

Whenever you are converting between dates, you must consider the relevant timezone, as this is the only way for the system to determine how to switch between date formats, make comparisions and output specific dates and times. For example, if you want to convert a date and time to a timestamp, the system must know the timezone of the input date and time so it can convert properly. Take a look at `strtotime`:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Unix timestamps are GMT timezone, so make sure you convert your datetimes accordingly. HTH.

Comment: I am in GMT+3 timezone. How do I effect this in my function above?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you need to set the correct timezone before calling `getTimestamp`

Comment: I have done exactly that using this function. date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Nairobi');

Comment: The dates and timestamps you posted in your question make sense because when it's midnight in your set timezone, it's 21:00:00 at GMT.  The timestamp reflects the 21:00:00 time because all timestamps are GMT by design. If you want to convert a timestamp to another format and timezone, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883757/convert-utc-datetime-to-another-timezone-php