# Laravel - Sending a date from the server to the client on their Timezone

Tags: php, date, timezone

I have a web app with Laravel that works as follows:

1. A user inputs their email to log in
2. A short-lived token is stored in the database, along with an expiration date
3. An email is sent to the user, with that code, as well as the expiration date.

You can probably already spot the problem. When i create the email, what I send is the Server Time. The user may be in a whole different timezone altogether.

If this was a website that I was showing, I might be able to fix this with JavaScript, but this is an email that we are talking about. Which means that the corrected Date/Time has to be crafted on the server.

How could I do this?

Comment: Does the user 'tell' you their timezone when they sign up?

Comment: NO. That would make it quite easy :) But I want to minimize the workload for the user.

Comment: One way would be to grab their IP, lookup the contry based upon their IP, and then assign the timezone using that. But that seems like alot of work. I'd just send them "your token expires in 48 hours" from now, or even "your token expires on Wednesday 12:00 UTC"

Comment: Try creating a hidden input on the same form with the email to login and setting the onsubmit function to fill in that input with javascript with the users date/time.  Then you can just send this time instead of the server time.

Comment: Just tell him how many minutes, hours or days it will last, no matter what timezone he is it will last that exact amount of time. I'd rather read `It will last 45 minutes.` instead of `It'll last until 2014-08-07 13:36:45 +4:00`.

Comment: @TheShiftChanger: Sounds a little flimsy...

Comment: @user3158900: That works, except if the user has no JS running...

Comment: @Ben, Maybe your option is indeed more practical. But since we are on the topic, I would like an answer if possible :)

Comment: @user3158900 What if they set their local date to the past or to year 2365?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stick to a standard timezone like `UTC` or `GMT` (or whatever you fancy the most) and tell your users their token will expire on `2014-08-07 13:36:45 UTC`.

You could also tell them how many minutes, hours or days the token will last instead of showing them a full date. It's always nicer to read `will last 45 minutes.` instead of `will last until 2014-08-07 13:36:45 UTC`. This way, no matter what timezone the user is, 45 minutes will always last 45 minutes.

Now, you can only guess the user's timezone by their IP address but it'll be just that, a guess. They could be behind a proxy, their ISP could not show you their real location, they could be behind a VPN, etc.

When it comes to dates you don't want to guess, you want to stick with a standard timezone.

Comment: While not a solution to my problem, since there seems to be no other solution available yet, I will accept it, until something better comes along. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Dbugger if, by any chance, you decide to let the user specify their country or timezone, you can check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883757/convert-utc-datetime-to-another-timezone-php).