# date format issue using php

Tags: php, date

This is not an duplicate question. I am using a php `date` function for format a date.

my `date` value is : `close_date:08/25/2017`.

This is php function : `$close_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($close_date));`

print the `close_date` , result is : `2017-08-26`.

my timezone is  : `-5:00` and server is on `UTC` , so at time of format date , date is convert into the utc date ?

so `date` is just format the date or convert date as per set `timezone` ?

Help me to solve this problem.

**I don't want to convert my date to any timezone date, i just want to change format of the date.**

My Input is: **08/25/2017**

Expected output is: **2017-08-25**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert UTC datetime to another timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883757/how-to-convert-utc-datetime-to-another-timezone)

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Please share your input and expected output.

Comment: try this `$close_date="08/25/2017";
    echo $close_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($close_date));`

Comment: Need to set your default timezone within your file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case, you don't want to use PHP **`date`** function they try to use `DateTime::createFromFormat` OR write some manual code stuff to explode `$close_date` and use it a way you want.

**1st Method:**

Use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). This will help you to parse a time string according to a specified format.

```
$close_date = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y", $close_date)->format("Y-m-d");
```

**2nd Method:**

Use some manual code:

```
$close_date = "08/25/2017";
$date_vars = preg_split("#/#", $close_date); 
print_r($date_vars);
```

then use `$date_vars` to convert in required format like following code:

```
$close_date = $date_vars[2]."-".$date_vars[0]."-".$date_vars[1];
```

P.S: You can also use PHP [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to explode the date values.

Comment: Right! =) Just to parse a time string according to a specified format.

Comment: If you may want any timezone manipulation then use `setTimezone` at the end. Check it here: [createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use DateTime to create date object from desired format and convert it to format you need.

```
DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y","08/25/2017")->format("Y-m-d");
```

Comment: you sure , this date not depend on any timezone?

Comment: @chiragsatapara It just parses a time string according to a specified format.

Comment: You said you just need to convert dates, in case of timezone  manipulation you may use DateTime class as well -  DateTime::setTimeZone();